# Slides App: getActivePresentation error after v8 migration

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, v8, google-slides

---

Seems to happen when you are logged in with 2 different accounts to Google and test the app - 1 account in Chrome browser and another in Google Slides app or Apps Script panel.

Other than that, all works fine.

---

I have a function `imageToSlide` called from html template like this:

```
google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(sidebar.onSuccess)
  .withFailureHandler(sidebar.onAddDocumentError)
  .imageToSlide(url, link, width, height);
```

Inside it I do `var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();`

After switching to V8 runtime I get an error:

> Exception: Action not allowed

It is not a container-bound script. It works without issues in `DEPRECATED_ES5` mode.

[Google docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slides-app#getActivePresentation()) say:

> If the presentation is already open, the same presentation instance is returned.

---

I tried using `SlidesApp.openById(id)` getting presentation id from the event passed to `onOpen` -> `e.source.getId()` but still did not work.

Comment: How do you publish the WebApp and with which access permissions? Also, please add your relevant Apps Script code. If the issue only occurs when you are logged in with two accounts, then probably you open the WebApp with a different account than the one with which you created it.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @ziganotschka And yes, you are right. It happened that I logged in with Slides with account A, but accidentially signed into account B with my extension (I developed an extension for Google slides).

How can provide people with a sign-out button for my extension? So they can correct their mistake.

Comment: Implementing a button into your extension is a very different topic, the easiest would probably be just informing the users about the necessity to sign out.